# Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (3 vs. 0) initialization error *** Check failure stack trace: **

Tags: caffe

I am very new to cuda and caffe. In my code I am using one caffe model for one textline detection and another caffe model for chracAter recognition. After detecting the textlines, I am processing all the textlines in parallel for segmentation and then recognition. However, while doing recognition I get the error as follows:

```
I0503 14:40:41.661458  3996 net.cpp:436] Input 0 -> data
I0503 14:40:41.661509  3996 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer scale
I0503 14:40:41.661527  3996 net.cpp:111] Creating Layer scale
I0503 14:40:41.661536  3996 net.cpp:478] scale <- data
I0503 14:40:41.661545  3996 net.cpp:434] scale -> scaled
I0503 14:40:41.661563  3996 net.cpp:156] Setting up scale
I0503 14:40:41.661576  3996 net.cpp:164] Top shape: 1 1 20 20 (400)
I0503 14:40:41.661583  3996 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer conv1
I0503 14:40:41.661597  3996 net.cpp:111] Creating Layer conv1
I0503 14:40:41.661605  3996 net.cpp:478] conv1 <- scaled
I0503 14:40:41.661615  3996 net.cpp:434] conv1 -> conv1
F0503 14:40:41.661710  3996 syncedmem.hpp:19] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (3 vs. 0)  initialization error
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: does your model work in `CPU` mode? Provide detail of your setup.

Comment: error might indicate old.cuda drive: https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/codeyarns.com/2011/06/17/cuda-initialization-error/amp/

Comment: @Shai: I removed the CUDA tag for a reason. Even *if* this turns out to be related to a broken CUDA installation, that doesn't make it an on-topic CUDA programming question.

Comment: @Inman My model works in GPU mode. The out put of the cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version is : NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  361.93.02  Wed Sep 21 16:32:29 PDT 2016
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Comment: @Shai I checked the link. However, had the problem been with cuda driver, none of my program using cuda should have worked. But I am able to use cuda using single caffe network model.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. and now there are some suggestions maybe help you.

1. init the whole caffe net for each thread.
2. the `Caffe::mode_` variable that controls this is thread-local, so ensure you're calling `caffe.set_mode_gpu()` in each thread before running any Caffe functions.
3. using the threading module instead of the multiprocessing module.